# ArrayList sorting using Comparator for object

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have Model class which contains

```
int rs;
String name;
```

I want to get rs > 8

ArrayList contains all data

```
  Collections.sort(arreyList, new Comparator< Model >() {

        public int compare(Model one, Model other) {

    int a = one.getrs();
    int b = other.getrs();
            if (a > 8) {
                if (a > b)
                    return -1;
                else if (a < b)
                    return 1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

but i am getting wrong , and I want to add more filter like > , < , or only that then for string also.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?. clarify your question.

Comment: i want from my arreylist get only rs 8 above

Comment: Your innermost `if/else if/else` can be replaced simply by `Integer.compare(b, a)`.

Comment: Also: Comparators should be anti-symmetrical, so that `compare(a, b) == -compare(b, a)` - this isn't, because you are only considering `a > 8`, and not `b > 8`.

Comment: "i want to get rs > 8" Do you mean you want only the elements for which `rs > 8`? Comparators can't do that - you need to filter the list first.

Comment: and between 8 to 10 ? basically i have to for loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Java 8**.

Use something like this.

```
 List<Model> completeModels = new ArrayList<>();

        completeModels.add(new Model(5, "Joe"));
        completeModels.add(new Model(3, "John"));
        completeModels.add(new Model(8, "Smith"));
        completeModels.add(new Model(10, "Lary"));

        List<Model> filtered = completeModels.stream().filter(u -> u.rs > 8).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will give you a list of Models with `rs>8` .

For more reference google 'java 8 filter examples' or go through [Stream Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

**EDIT**

Otherwise(if you are not using java 8) write a method to get the list filtered. I don't know other ways to do this.

eg:

```
private List<Model> getFilteredList(List<Model> completeModels) {

    List<Model> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Model m : completeModels) {
        if (m.rs > 8) {
            filtered.add(m);
        }
    }

    return filtered;
}
```

Comment: java 8 not supported yet in andorid